# Mocking __init__() for unittesting

Tags: python, sqlite, unit-testing, mocking

I have a class:

```
class DatabaseThing():
     def __init__(self, dbName, user, password):
          self.connection = ibm_db_dbi.connect(dbName, user, password)
```

I want to test this class but with a test database. So in my test class I am doing something like this:

```
import sqlite3 as lite
import unittest
from DatabaseThing import *

class DatabaseThingTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.connection = lite.connect(":memory:")
        self.cur = self.connection.cursor()
        self.cur.executescript ('''CREATE TABLE APPLE (VERSION INT, AMNT SMALLINT);
            INSERT INTO APPLE VALUES(16,0);
            INSERT INTO APPLE VALUES(17,5);
            INSERT INTO APPLE VALUES(18,1);
            INSERT INTO APPLE VALUES(19,15);
            INSERT INTO APPLE VALUES(20,20);
            INSERT INTO APPLE VALUES(21,25);''')
```

How would I go about using this connection than the connection from the class I want to test? Meaning using the connection from `setUp(self)` instead of the connection from `DatabaseThing`. I cannot test the functions without instantiating the class. I want to mock the `__init__` method somehow in the Test Class, but I didn't find anything that seemed useful in the [documentation](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/).

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Instead of mocking, you could simply subclass the database class and test against that:

```
class TestingDatabaseThing(DatabaseThing):
     def __init__(self, connection):
          self.connection = connection
```

and instantiate **that** class instead of `DatabaseThing` for your tests. The methods are still the same, the behaviour will still be the same, but now all methods using `self.connection` use your test-supplied connection instead.

Answer (score 26):

If you want to return a mock when you initialize a class, mock out the__new__ method, not **init**.

**new** makes the new instance and **init** initializes it, but can only return None.

If you mock **new**, it can return a mock you can assert on to simulate instance creation in the test.

```
@mock.patch('Car.__new__')
def test_create_car(self, mock_Car):
    mock_inst = mock.MagickMock()
    mock_Car.return_value = mock_inst

    create_car()

    # Assert class was called
    mock_Car.assert_called_once()
    # __new__ is called with actual class as first arg
    mock_Car.assert_called_with(Car) 

    # Assert instance method is called as expected
    mock_inst.set_miles.assert_called_with(0)
```

Comment: @mauricio777 I wonder why it's not mentioned in the docs? I only see mocking the classname, not the __new__ method.

Answer (score 14):

You should use `mock` package to mock the method `__init__` of the class:

```
from mock import patch


def test_database_thing(self):
    def __init__(self, dbName, user, password):
        # do something else
    with patch.object(DatabaseThing, '__init__', __init__):
        # assert something
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Can you patch the object inside a setup fixture?

Answer (score 5):

#### Inversion of Control

A long term solution is to have the client create the connection and hand it over to `DatabaseThing` to use. Using the Single Responsibility principle, I don't think `DatabaseThing` should be responsible for making the connection in this case.

This technique cuts dependencies and gives you a lot more flexibility e.g. you can setup a connection pool and give each new instance of `DatabaseThing` a connection from the pool, without changing anything in `DatabaseThing`.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than try to replace the **init** function which is messy, fragile and hacky, try passing a function to your database constructor as shown below:

```
# Test connection creation
def connect_lite(dbName=None, user=None, password=None):
    connection = lite.connect(":memory:")
    cur = self.connection.cursor()
    cur.executescript ('''CREATE TABLE APPLE (VERSION INT, AMNT SMALLINT);
                          INSERT INTO APPLE VALUES(16,0);
                          INSERT INTO APPLE VALUES(17,5);
                          INSERT INTO APPLE VALUES(18,1);
                          INSERT INTO APPLE VALUES(19,15);
                          INSERT INTO APPLE VALUES(20,20);
                          INSERT INTO APPLE VALUES(21,25);''')
    return cur


# Production connection creation
def connect_ibm(dbName, user, password):
    return ibm_db_dbi.connect(dbName, user, password)

# Your DatabaseThing becomes:
class DatabaseThing():
    def __init__(self, connect, dbName, user, password):
        self.connection = connect(dbName, user, password)

# In your test create a DatabaseThing
t = DatabaseThing(connect_lite, dbName, user, password)

# In your production code create a DatabaseThing
p = DatabaseThing(connect_ibm, dbName, user, password)
```

This has the side benefit of slightly decoupling your code from the database technology you are using.

Comment: This won't be an option. I don't have write access to the constructor. I just write the test cases.

Comment: @parzival In that case you can wrap DatabaseThing in a new class TestDatabaseThing and do not call `super(self, DatabaseThing).__init__` from your wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

Considering `ibm_db_dbi` and `lite` share the same interfaces, this should do the trick:

```
import mock
import sqlite3 as lite

class DatabaseThingTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.patch = mock.patch('module_with_DatabaseThing_definition.ibm_db_dbi', lite)
        self.patch.start()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.patch.stop()
```

I.e. your `DatabaseThing` file is named `database/things.py` then the patch would look like this `database.things.ibm_db_dbi`.

Example of the mocking:

**moduleA.py**

```
def connection(*args):
    print 'The original connection. My args', args
```

**moduleB.py**

```
def connection(*args):
    print 'The mocked connection. My args', args
```

**myClass.py**

```
import moduleA


class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = moduleA.connection('Test', 'Connection')
```

**test.py**

```
import mock
import moduleB

from myClass import MyClass


def regular_call():
    MyClass()


def mocked_call():
    def wrapped_connection(*args):
        return moduleB.connection(':memory:')

    my_mock = mock.Mock(wraps=moduleB)
    my_mock.connection = wrapped_connection
    with mock.patch('myClass.moduleA', my_mock):
        MyClass()

    MyClass()

regular_call()
mocked_call()
```

Running **test.py** gives:

```
The original connection. My args ('Test', 'Connection')
The mocked connection. My args (':memory:',)
The original connection. My args ('Test', 'Connection')
```

Comment: How would I setup an in-memory DB, like in the question above, with this method?

Comment: You could either mock the `lite.connect` method with a mock that would call the `lite.connect(':memory:')` no matter arguments, or make a mock that `wraps` the connect method and does the same as above

Comment: I am sorry I am having trouble getting my head around your suggestion. I'd really really appreciate if you could edit the code above or put up a link or something. :)

Comment: Updated my answer with an example.