# problems with staticmethod decorators

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, static-methods

I have been using `@staticmethod` decorator on some of my functions in order to write test cases for them. I just wanted to test a few methods in the class without having to initialize the entire class, so I thought this would be a perfect way to do.

But, now test code runs fine but the actual code gives me an error. Most of the functions had `self` parameters passed to them, so `@staticmethod` decorators result in their failures.

Is there a way to test methods without using `@staticmethod`? If there isn't, what would be the perfect way to work around this without changing much of the production code?

```
Class DBMethod():
      @staticmethod
      def getVN(self, tN):
          curs = self.connection.cursor()
          curs.execute ('SELECT * FROM ' + tN)
          vL = list(map(lambda x: x[0], curs.description))[0]
          return vL
```

And Test class

```
Class DBTestClass(unittest.TestCase):
      def test_getVN(self):
            self.assertEqual(DBMethod.getVN(self, 'tbN'), 'VER')
```

Comment: `staticmethods` are *just* like functions; they do *not* take a `self` argument because they are independent of any instances. What do you expect `self` to be here?

Comment: There is no option to only initialize 'partially'; static methods are not a method to get there either. It is all or nothing; static methods is 'nothing'; regular methods need 'all'.

Comment: Yeah I get it. I didn't realize it when I started writing the test codes. Apparently most of the production code depend on having a `self` parameter there.

Comment: The `self` parameter refers to the instance, which holds the database connection, for example.

Comment: I cannot really initialize the class (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836939/mocking-init-for-unittesting/17902286). I have been using in-memory database instead. `@staticmethod` seemed like a way to go without having to overload or mock the init method. Now I am stuck.

Comment: How about a subclass for testing? Or update the class `__init__` to let you inject a test database connection?

Comment: Modifying the production code to fit the test code doesn't seem like a good practice to me. So I have been refraining myself from doing that.

Comment: This is not the way to go, no. `@staticmethod` completely changes the meaning of a method (it is no longer a method); I thought you were trying to refrain from modifying production code?

Comment: Yeah I didn't "really" think decorators would do much to the production code. D'oh!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you use one of the available testing frameworks for Python such as:

- [unittest](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html)
- [nose](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)
- [pytest](http://pytest.org/latest/)

These frameworks make it easy to write tests that exercise each method in a class and to provide appropriate test scaffolding and test data as required. Much easier IMHO than trying to handcraft tests.

Answer (score 0):

The following mock patch can skip the **init** part (Actually I do not know why you avoid "mock the init method" here, so paste my guess here):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import unittest
from mock import patch


class DBThing(object):
    moo = "bar"

    def __init__(self):
        self.moo = "hi"

    def foo(self):
        return self.moo

class Test_init(unittest.TestCase):
    """Test DBThing init"""
    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def tearDown(self):
        pass

    def testInit(self):
        dbt = DBThing()
        self.assertEqual(dbt.foo(), "hi")

    def testNoInit(self):
        with patch('__main__.DBThing.__init__', return_value=None):
            dbt = DBThing()
            self.assertEqual(dbt.foo(), "bar")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import nose
    nose.run(defaultTest=__name__)
```

Comment: much appreciated. I am sorry I could not verify your method though. I ended up using another workaround that would allow me avoid `@staticmethod` altogether.