# mock __init__(self, ...): TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking

I try to mock the constructor of a class like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/17950141/633961

```
class MockedHttpResponse(django.http.response.HttpResponseBase):
    def check(self, *args, **kwargs):
        status=kwargs.get('status')
        if status is None and self.status_code==200:
            return # default 
        if not status==self.status_code:
            raise self.AssertionErrorStatusCode('%s!=%s' % (self.status_code, status))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.check(*args, **kwargs)
        django.http.response.HttpResponseBase.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    class AssertionErrorStatusCode(AssertionError):
        pass
```

usage in test:

```
def test_assert_http_response_status__with_self_mocking(self):
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    with mock.patch('django.http.response.HttpResponse', testutils.MockedHttpResponse):
        HttpResponse(status=200)
```

But I get this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/foo_eins_di514/src/djangotools/djangotools/tests/unit/utils/test_testutils.py", line 129, in test_assert_http_response_status__with_self_mocking
    HttpResponse(status=200)
  File "/home/foo_eins_di514/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/response.py", line 258, in __init__
    super(HttpResponse, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

How can I mock a class and modify its `__init__()` method?

Comment: Which version of Django are you using?

Comment: @SilasRay we use Django 1.5.8

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure since I'm not an expert on how `mock` works, but unless it's doing some very impressive gymnastics, you've statically bound the original `django.http.HttpResponse` object to `HttpResponse` within the test module scope (`from django.http import HttpResponse`).  Unless `mock` is dynamically modifying `locals()` \ `globals()` within the context manager to patch over aliased references to the patch target, no amount of patching on the module itself will impact the `HttpResponse` object you are using in the test.  I think at least one step you need to take is to reference the class from the module explicitly within the `patch` context manager, though it looks like you could also use `with mock.patch('django.http.response.HttpResponse', testutils.MockedHttpResponse) as HttpResponse:` to get the desired result.  I think you may also want to use `new_callable=testutils.MockedHttpResponse` as a kwarg to `patch`.