# How can i mock __init__ in python

Tags: python

This is my class structure.

```
class DataLoader:
    #some stuff
    
class ABC:
    def get_loader(key1, key2)
        loader = DataLoader(key1, key2)
        return loader

class TestABC:
    def setUp():
        self.obj =  ABC()
    
    def test_get_loader()
        ret = self.obj.get_loader(1, 2)  # here I don't want to call actual DataLoader, instead mocked DataLoader should be return.
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mocking \_\_init\_\_() for unittesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836939/mocking-init-for-unittesting). See the second answer

Comment: This is a little too minimal; is there a reason you need a wrapper around creating the `DataLoader` instance in the first place? I would try to avoid that so mocking isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best ways i've stumbled upon before is this one below (if someone remembers the reference it would be great to give them credits):

```
with patch.object(DataLoader, "__init__", lambda x, y, z: None):
    ret=DataLoader(None,#insert as many None as the number of your constructor arguments in dataloader that you want to be set to None, else insert your values)
    #you can access its properties with:
    var=ret.name_of_property
    #you can use assert to test
    assert ret.function(arg1,arg2)==value
```

The lambda function is added there as an imitation of the `__init__` since they have both 3 arguments and they return `None`.