# Mock a method in __init__

Tags: python, pytest

I want to write a test case which mocks a method in `__init__`. Below is my code:

```
#rds_service.py

class RDS_service:
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.user, self.pwd = get_con(url)
        self.user = self.user + "@gmail.com"
```

```
#test_rds_service.py

import unittest.mock import patch
from src.service.rdsservice import RDS_service

@patch('service.rdsservice.RDS_service.__init__')
def test_rds_service(mock_conn_info):
    mock_conn_info.get_con.return_value = 'user', 'pwd'
    obj = rds_service()
    assert (obj.user, "foo@gmail.com")
```

I want to mock `get_con` in `__init__` and need to assert that value in the test case

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836939/mocking-init-for-unittesting  this answer will helps you

Comment: `@patch('service.rdsservice.get_con')`

Comment: You're trying to patch the whole method, not the thing it _calls_.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Pasted in too much. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, in this scenario it is best to simply mock `get_con`. That is the function that is returning the value that we want to have control over.

```
from unittest.mock import patch

import pytest

from src.service.rds_service import RDS_service


@patch("src.service.rds_service.get_con")
@pytest.mark.parametrize("user", ["foo", "fizz", "buzz"])
def test_rds_service(mock_get_con, user):
    mock_get_con.return_value = user, "abc123"
    obj = RDS_service("fizzbuzz")
    assert obj.user == f"{user}@gmail.com"
```